# how to convert below native query into queryDSL. It has subquery where actual resultset will be populated from it.

Tags: querydsl

I'm trying to convert below query into QueryDSL, I don't know how to get actual results from the subquery resultsets. I just want to group by things on subquery resultset and populate actual result set from it.

```
select ha.host_model, ha.MACHINE_TYPE, ha.END_OF_LIFE_DT,
                    ha.END_OF_SERVICE_LIFE_DT,
                    ha.END_OF_SALE_DT,
                    ha.END_OF_ENGINEERING_DT,
                    ha.SOFT_MAINTENANCE_END_DT,
                    ha.CONTRACT_RENEWAL_END_DT  from (
    SELECT distinct h.host_id,
                    h.host_model,
                    h.MACHINE_TYPE,
                    m.manufacturer_name,
                    o.host_platform,
                    e.END_OF_LIFE_DT,
                    e.END_OF_SERVICE_LIFE_DT,
                    e.END_OF_SALE_DT,
                    e.END_OF_ENGINEERING_DT,
                    e.SOFT_MAINTENANCE_END_DT,
                    e.CONTRACT_RENEWAL_END_DT
               FROM tf_host h
                    JOIN tf_eol e
                       ON h.eol_id = e.eol_id
                    JOIN tf_manufacturer m 
                       ON h.manufacturer_id = m.manufacturer_id 
                    JOIN tf_os o
                       ON h.os_id = o.os_id
              WHERE HOST_SERVERFLAG = 0) ha group by ha.host_model, ha.MACHINE_TYPE, ha.END_OF_LIFE_DT,
                    ha.END_OF_SERVICE_LIFE_DT,
                    ha.END_OF_SALE_DT,
                    ha.END_OF_ENGINEERING_DT,
                    ha.SOFT_MAINTENANCE_END_DT,
                    ha.CONTRACT_RENEWAL_END_DT
              order by ha.host_model;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `PathBuilder` and select the elements from the subquery using the `get` method. Declare the path as `PathBuilder<Tuple> ha = new PathBuilder<>(Tuple.class, "ha")`. Think of this as creating the alias `ha` for your subquery. Next alias the subquery to the path by using `.as(ha)` on the subquery object. Finally reference the columns using `ha.get(tableName.columnName)`.